# Connect to Sharepoint using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to node. I need to do the following.

1. Connect and request to a SHarepoint portal using node js
2. Retrieve the response [may be a document or excel] from Portal
3. Store the response in Mongo DB

How to implement this? Kindly let me know any sharepoint API's or sample code or reference for the above scenario. Kindly help. THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched the [npm registry](http://npmjs.org)?  It contains, amongst others, [this module](https://github.com/lstak/node-sharepoint).

For storing files in MongoDB, have a look at [GridStore](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/gridfs.html)

Comment: Werner, to store and retrieve the documents or excel in mongo db any idea? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This link could suffice the above requirement. Could be useful to someone who may looking for node js with sharepoint.
node-sharepoint-rest
https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-sharepoint-rest